# Install .NuPKG on VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I have seen 4+ different answers, some of which say "But doesn't work on VS 2017" (which I have).
Sshould be straightforwad, but nothing is.

I have FluentFTP.NuPKG sitting in a local folder on C:\vs2017\FTP\FluentFTP.Nupkg
I'm running VS 2017
With this combination, how do I install?

Comment: Thank you KEN!  The NuGet site for FluentFTP kinda misdirects people by saying "Download Here..." which is why I did!.  Excellent Graphic!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really NEED to install a NuGet package from a local file, by far the easiest way to do it is via the NuGet manager in Visual Studio itself. You can right-click on your Project and select "Manage NuGet Packages..." or right-click on your Solution and select "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...". The process is basically the same for both, with the only real difference being that the latter approach allows you to quickly add the same package to multiple Projects if you need to do that.

[image: Click here to see a visual of the steps involved to find and install the package.]

Comment: Although this answer will probably help most people who are trying to install NuGet packages, it's not an answer to the question asked by the OP.  Do you know how to do it from a local file?

Comment: Please see below for adding a local nupkg.

Answer (score 0):

The little gear in the corner will pop open a window that will allow you to navigate to your nupkg.

[image: Screen shot new package manager.]